# WooCommerce: Display on-sale products in shop

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

There are plenty of questions and answers regarding making only on-sale products display, but no matter what one I try, it doesn't work.

I have the following query

```
function my_modify_main_query($query) {
    if ($query -> query['post_type'] == 'product' && $query -> is_main_query() && is_shop()) {// Run only on the shop
        if (isset($_GET['sale'])):
            $query -> set('meta_query',
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    array(// Simple products type
                        'key' => '_sale_price',
                        'value' => 0,
                        'compare' => '>',
                        'type' => 'numeric'
                    ),
                    array(// Variable products type
                        'key' => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                        'value' => 0,
                        'compare' => '>',
                        'type' => 'numeric'
                    )
                )
            );
        endif;
    }
}
// Hook my above function to the pre_get_posts action
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_modify_main_query' );
```

The query itself is being applied, BUT the problem is.
If the Product has been a variable with a sale price, the Product is then changed to a Simple Product, the "_min_variation_sale_price" meta value is still in the database.

Does anybody know of a workaround for this? I believe it to be a bug, but their support is closed currently.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

What I think I need is a way to  only check _sale_price if the product is in the "simple" or "external" terms, then do similar for _min_variation_sale_price.

I have created an issue on their github.
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/10096

**EDIT**

Issue is fixed using @helgatheviking answer.
Although, take note that to resolve the issue completely, you must delete the variations, save, change the type, save, run `delete_transient( 'wc_products_onsale' );`
Only then did it work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my tutorial on [modifying the product query](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-modifying-product-query/)

I believe this should modify the loop to only show the on-sale products:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'so_20990199_product_query' );

function so_20990199_product_query( $q ){

    $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

    $q->set( 'post__in', (array) $product_ids_on_sale );

}
```

Comment: Next time, please mention all things you *have* tried so there's less duplication of effort. Are you implying that `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` does not retrieve variable products that are on sale?

Comment: When you save a product as a variable with a sale, then change it to a simple without a sale, it returns in that array.

Comment: @helgatheviking, how can i get most famous categories by sale? please help.

Comment: @MahaDev You will have to post a new question, but please be sure that it is clear and detailed. Explain what you are trying to do, and why what you have tried has failed so far. Currently, I don't understand what you are asking and comments on other questions aren't the place to work this out.

Comment: @Damian The on sale products *are* stored in a transient `wc_products_onsale` so you could try clearing that. It seems like switching from variable to simple products is a rare occurrence, but you might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues) to suggest that `delete_transient( 'wc_products_onsale' );` should be triggered when a simple product saves.

Comment: Nice one, this works well, thanks. One thing to point out - if there are no products on sale then this filter doesn't apply at all, because WP_Query assumes the empty array means (don't filter). Therefore, if you want the query to return no results when there's no products on sale, you can check if `wc_get_product_ids_on_sale()` returned empty and pass an array with a single 0 element (i.e. `array(0)`) to the `post__in` clause.

Comment: is there any alternative way to achieve the same requirement (like WP_QUERY)

Comment: @Ifat currently the product query is still eventually resolving to us `WP_Query`. but you could do that same thing re: `post__in` parameter since that's also accepted by `WP_Query`

Comment: @helgatheviking
 yes I've figure out  that actually works.